# How to put a button into each card?

Tags: livecode

I'd like to put a 'next' button onto each card of a stack. In Hypercard I could put buttons into either cards or backgrounds. I have not seen yet how it is possible to make a button appear on each card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LiveCode you can create a background group that can be on every card. First **create** your **button(s)** select it (them) and press "**group**" in the toolbar. That will create a group. **In the inspector** for the group you then **select "Behave like a background"**. All new cards will have your button(s) automatically. If you already created a bunch of cards you can always add the group by selecting "Object => Place Group => " in the menu.

Comment: http://docs.runrev.com/Property/backgroundBehavior ---  Use the backgroundBehavior property to make groups behave like HyperCard backgrounds, and to automatically place groups on newly created cards.

Comment: see also http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/13031-How-do-I-use-the-same-controls-on-multiple-cards-

Comment: See also http://livecode.byu.edu/groups/Groups.php for an overview of the group object in LiveCode.

Answer (score 1):

Backgrounds are probably the single biggest thing to unlearn if you're coming from a HyperCard background because they act a bit differently in LiveCode. But they have a *lot* more power than the old HC backgrounds did, so the pain in making the transition pays off well in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for this note. In the user's guide I found chapter 4.2.26 Groups & Backgrounds – for organizing, and sharing controls. I understand that a group may be considered a background in many cases. For this to happen *Behave like a background* has to be selected as a propertly of the group as Hliljegren noted. Where do you see more power of the groups? That several of them may be combined on one card?  Can I store data in a background? What else is more powerful?

Comment: Yes you can store data in a background (as you can in any object!) You can set a custom property of the group. You also have the inheritance of properties in group, you can place groups in other groups etc, but now we are walking away from the main question.